# Execute query with Criteria API without FROM statement

Tags: java, sql, criteria-api

How to create Criteria API query like

```
SELECT
  (select count(*) from table1),
  (select count(*) from table2),
  (select count(*) from table3)
```

Note: there is no FROM statement in main query

Update: i'm using postgreSQL and i need create exactly Criteria API query, like:

```
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = getSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Long[]> mainQuery= criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Long[].class);

    Subquery<Long> subQuery1= mainQuery.subquery(Long.class);
    Root<Table1> subQuery1Root = subQuery1.from(Table1.class);
    subQuery1.select(criteriaBuilder.count(subQuery1Root));

    Subquery<Long> subQuery2= mainQuery.subquery(Long.class);
    Root<Table2> subQuery2Root = subQuery2.from(Table2.class);
    subQuery2.select(criteriaBuilder.count(subQuery2Root));
```

Comment: Invalid ANSI SQL. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: You can simply do UNION ALL instead. Or do CROSS JOINS.

Comment: @jarlh But that might not work with his Java code.  Actually, the syntax is valid for MySQL, and possibly a few others.

Comment: If you don't get a satisfactory answer here, you could always consider just running it as a raw query.  Not that flexible, but it might get around your problem for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

ANSI SQL alternative:

```
SELECT *
from
  (select count(*) from table1) t1 cross join
  (select count(*) from table2) t2 cross join
  (select count(*) from table3) t3
```